# Mail Password Bug

Tags: macos, mac, mail.app, email, password

I have been having an issue with Mail.app.

After I create an account, even if i do define the password (whether it be via programmatically doing so using applescript OR manually), after I save my changes and close the "Preferences" frame for Mail in which the password can be changed, the password text box resets to be blank. NONE of the other properties change (the username, email, servers etc all are saved and do not reset to be blank text boxes). Here's a visual of the preferences frame with the blank password box issue:

[image: As you can see, the password box is blank and even if i manually change the password and save changes, when I re-open the same preferences window after closing it, the password box is blank once again.]

As you can see, the password box is blank and even if i manually change the password and save changes, when I re-open the same preferences window after closing it, the password box is blank once again.

Here is a screenshot of the "Advanced" settings pane:
[image]

I have tried:
-Deleting the com.apple.mail.plist file in ~/Library/Preferences
-Deleting any trace of the account in the keychain
-Restarting my computer

None of the above works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your password saved in the key chain ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 No it's not

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've manually set up your email account instead of using the wizard... you should be using IMap instead of POP with a Yahoo account.

delete the account and re-add it using the wizard.

Comment: Could you elaborate what wizard do you recommend ?

Comment: in System Preferences, go to Internet Accounts, click the plus and select Yahoo, then fill in your user name and password.

Comment: @scoutelder using the wizard doesn't change anything (IMAP accounts have the same issue). just tried.

Comment: try creating a new user account, opening email and adding your account.

Comment: @scoutelder something weird happens. mail just stops responding after submitting the account info.